# Calculation of average bond length from force constant and IR absorption?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, quantum-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy

I need some help beginning a problem set problem (just want hints, I'd like to figure it out myself).

The problem gives me the IR absorption for a diatomic, as well as the force constant for the bond. It asks me to identify the the average separation (bond length) of the two atoms.

I am stuck because the typical Schrodinger equation for harmonic oscillation takes "displacement from equilibrium length" as its variable: $\hat{H}\psi_{v}(x)=E_{v}\psi_{v}(x)$. A change of variables such as $x = l-l_{0}$ would require I know the average separation, which I am trying to solve for.

Any help or direction to relevant resources is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can get the bond lenght via rotational transitions, using the rotational inertia $I=µr^2$, where µ is the reduced mass. From pure vibrational data i don't think it works ... ?

Comment: As @Karl mentions, vibrational spectroscopy does not provide any information about bond lengths. Only if a vibrational-rotational (in the infra-red) or pure rotational (microwave) spectrum is measured can bond lengths be obtained.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments above, one usually needs information on the rotational structure to extract rotational constants and bond lengths. However, if you are willing to make some crude approximations you can estimate the order of magnitude of the bond length by calculating the classical turning points for the harmonic oscillator using the force constant and the reduced mass of your molecule.

Comment: See this [analysis for HCl](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/molecule/vibrot.html).

Comment: Of course if you have the well resolved IR spectrum of a diatomic gas, you have the necessary information about both vibrational and rotational transitions to calculate force constant and bond lenght. If the substance *has* an IR spectrum, that is, i.e. it's not a diatomic element.

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps it's my misinterpretation/misunderstanding of the problem  $-$ we are given a single IR absorption, which suggested to me that it is discussing the fundamental frequency for oscillation. We are also given the force constant of the bond in $Nm^{-1}$ and enough information to find the reduced mass (it is a diatomic @Karl). They then ask for the average separation of the two atoms. Am I just misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Paul, an interesting idea but surely this type of calculation will only give the displacement relative to the average internuclear separation not the separation itself?

Comment: What is the actual wavenumber given? Is it an actual IR transition (e.g. $2900cm^{-1}$ for HCl) or a pure rotational microwave band, $~20cm^{-1}$? Otherwise I think there is a mixup in the question, not in your understanding. ;-)

Comment: @porphyrin, you're absolutely right of course, but I think one should get a rough idea of the order of magnitude of the bond length. After a bit more searching I came across a few articles who found empirical relations between the bond length and force constant (e.g. [R. M. Badger, J. Chem. Phys. 2, 128 (1934)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1749433)).  A more theoretical approach has been adopted in [J. Chem. Phys. 86, 4801 (1998)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.452702).

Comment: Been meaning to get back to y'all -- the professor admitted he should have given the average bond length, and that he intended the exercise to get us to conclude that the average deviation from equilibrium length is $0$.... Thank you guys for an opportunity to really grok the concept, though! I appreciate it.

Comment: @porphyrin https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1720/5

Comment: The method involves fitting the whole ir spectrum (or at least as much as can be measured)  to a guessed potential such as Morse so the value of the bond length is a parameters  and so must depend on the assumed potential, however, this can still be a good result for a diatomic. I would imagine that a polyatomic would be much more problematic as normal modes are involved.